# Can not find HttpContextBase even though I am using System.Web

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext

Code

```
using System.Web;

abstract class CookieHandler
{
    public CookieHandler(string domain)
    {
         CookieDomain = domain;
    }
    public string CookieDomain { get; set; }

    public abstract void SetCookie(HttpContextBase context, CookieHandler value);
}
```

HttpContextBase gives me the error "type or namespace HttpContextBase cannot be found" Same error when i try HttpContext. I am trying to figure out why I cannot take in this object anymore.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and have it has a Library class project.

Comment: Have you referenced the assembly _system.web.dll_? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wow. I derped. I forgot to check that since "using System.Web" didn't throw any warning signs. Thanks, I can't believe I forgot this.

Comment: @LordHoneydew I did the same thing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per recommendation from user comment, the issue was I had to reference the assembly system.web.dll